# How to assign all Skype for Business users to a specific policy in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, skype-for-business

So, I need to assign all users to a specific policy.
I know how to do this with individual users using the `-identity`.
I have tried using the below:

```
Get-CsOnlineUser | Grant-CsClientPolicy -PolicyName OfflineIM
```

Unfortunately, it fails.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. + CategoryInfo :
>   NotSpecified: (:) [Grant-CsClientPolicy], NullReferenceException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.AD.Cmdlets.AssignClientPolicy`1[[Microsoft.Rtc.Management.ADConnect.
>   Schema.OCSADUserOrAppContact, Microsoft.Rtc.Management.ADConnect,
>   Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b7f21e63458e5a11]] +
>   PSComputerName : admin2a.online.lync.com

Any ideas?

Comment: When "it fails" what happens?  Does it give you any error messages?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Grant-CsClientPolicy], NullReferenceException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.AD.Cmdlets.AssignClientPolicy`1[[Microsoft.Rtc.Management.ADConnect. 
Schema.OCSADUserOrAppContact, Microsoft.Rtc.Management.ADConnect, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b7f21e63458e5a11]]
+ PSComputerName        : admin2a.online.lync.com

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the comment to appear correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of [Get-OnlienCSUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/get-csonlineuser?view=skype-ps) probably means you're running Skype for Business Online. As such there might be additional restrictions. As for running [Grant-CSClientPolicy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/grant-csclientpolicy?view=skype-ps) it actually accepts Pipe input but might be unable to accept the input from `Get-CSOnlineUser`. You could try to run it the `Grant-CSClientPolicy` in a simple loop and directly identify an identity attribute.

For instance this could look like this:

```
Get-CsOnlineUser | %{Grant-CsClientPolicy -PolicyName OfflineIM -Identity $_.Identity}
```

You'd have to check whenever the objects returned by `Get-CSOnlineUser` has an `Identity` attribute. Alternatively an alias or distinguished name could work. Also make sure to check what `Get-CSOnlineUser` returns beforehand.